# Windows Firewall on WS2016 doesn't accept IPv6 loopback IP

Tags: ipv6, windows-firewall, windows-server-2016

I came to a problem when Windows Firewall on Windows Server 2016 is unable to set IPv6 loopback address to an inbound rule - Scope - Local IP address. The error is:

```
An error occurred while verifying the rule.
Error: The parameter is incorrect
Status: An unspecified, multicast, broadcast, or loopback IPv6 address was specified.
```

This is happening with when I try to add any of these values:

```
::1,::1/128,0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
```

I want to do this because I have an application running in the server. I want to specify a windows firewall rule for access to this application from LAN network or from specific IP addresses and also from localhost. When I try to access the app from localhost I am blocked because IPv6 loopback address is not in the scope of the windows firewall rule.

Comment: Loopback does not pass via the firewall.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. But why the 127.0.0.1 localhost IP can be added to WF without problems?

Comment: Might be that they didn't add a check to the config GUI, so you can add the address but it does nothing. Some other firewalls do filter loopback, but I agree that the Windows built-in firewall usually doesn't touch it. (Plenty of programs use loopback for internal communications and they never trigger firewall popups, after all.)